# Import CSV with double quote using mysqlimport.exe

Tags: mysql, csv, batch-file, mysqlimport

I have a csv file that I need to import to a remote Mysql DB.
The structure of the csv is as follow:

```
sep=,
"Affiliate ID","Affiliate Name","Affiliate First Name","Affiliate Surname","Affiliate Status","Affiliate E-mail","Marketing Source","Parent Affiliate ID","Parent Affiliate Name","Affiliate Groups","Signup Date","Affiliate Review Type","Country","Affiliate Type","Whois","Signup Comment",
"654673","Traffic A","A","B","Approved","a@ts","T","N/A","N/A","N/A","21/09/2022 14:22:00","Generic","UK","Generic","[WhoIS]","N/A",
"654672","TL","Joe","BI","Approved","info@aa.com","zoo","N/A","N/A","N/A","21/09/2022 08:23:00","Generic","India","Generic","[WhoIS]","N/A",
"654671","BJoe","J ","Doed","Approved","nee@gmail.com","you","N/A","N/A","N/A","21/09/2022 07:53:00","Generic","greece","Generic","[WhoIS]","N/A",
"654670","Collectc","ba","mo","Approved","bii@pq.co","youtube","N/A","N/A","N/A","21/09/2022 06:44:00","Generic","irland","Generic","[WhoIS]","N/A",
```

Before anything, I am deleting the first line including `sep=,` using the following script:

```
set "csv=C:\Users\SERVER\Downloads\Affiliates.csv"
more +1 "%csv%" >"%csv%.new"
move /y "%csv%.new" "%csv%" >nul
```

I then try to import the file using the mysqlimport function:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqlimport.exe" -h server.com -P 3306 -u user -pPassword --local --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='\"' --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" database C:\Users\SERVER\Downloads\Affiliates.csv
```

but it seems that my instruction `--fields-optionally-enclosed-by='\"'` fails

If i omit this instruction, the the file is properly imported to DB including the double quotes...

I do not know if there is a way to fix the mysqlimport instruction or if i need to remove all double quote in the csv file to allow an easier import...

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of `--fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"'` and I don't think you really need to pass `\`.

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqlimport.exe" -h server.com -P 3306 -u user -pPassword --local --ignore-lines=1 --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" database C:\Users\SERVER\Downloads\Affiliates.csv
```

Comment: Tried to change the order while using--fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' , no luck, pretty sure this is the issue since otherwise import works if omiting this